# Should objects with virtual member functions always be instantiated on the heap?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, heap-memory, virtual-functions

As far as I understand, objects of concrete types `D` with virtual member functions should be used through pointers to their (possibly abstract) base class `B`. Otherwise there is no point in making the functions virtual. There are three important "pointer options":

1. Raw pointer to `B` pointing to an object of type `D` on the stack.
2. Raw pointer to `B` pointing to an object of type `D` on the heap.
3. Owning smart pointer (unique or shared) to `B` pointing to an object of type `D` on the heap.

Option 2 is generally discouraged in favor of option 3. In object oriented programming, we often like to assemble complex objects out of simpler ones through composition. In this case option 3 offers the additional advantage of communicating ownership and managing object life times, e.g. objects of a class with a unique pointer member are responsible for the pointed to object and do not outlive the latter.

In consequence, is it good practice to always instantiate objects of classes with virtual member functions on the heap and have all factory functions return smart pointers?

Comment: *"should be used through pointers"* or references.

Answer (score 3):

> Otherwise there is no point in making the functions virtual.

- Yes, there is, here's an example:

```
// say this is a library interface
struct Base
{
    virtual hello() = 0;
}

// external to the library
class Derived
{
    hello() override { std::cout << "hello from Derived" << std::endl; }
}

// say this is a library function,
// which does not need to know about Derived
void sayHelloNTimes(Base& b, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        b.hello();
    }
}

int main() {
    Derived d;
    sayHelloNTimes(d, 3);
}
```

In general, the reason for using `virtual` is simply to decouple interface from implementation.

As for the question on smart pointers: you return them from a `create()` function (and make ctor, etc. private) when you want to ensure a specific ownership. An example is when the class retains a (handle to a) copy of the elements created. Another is when your common library functions need to do the same. Normally, don't limit it unless you have to.

Comment: Thanks. This example would work just as well with `sayHelloNTimes` being a template right? Because if we initialize `d` on the stack there is no possibility for runtime polymorphism anyways?

Comment: @Quappas Yes, it would work with templates, but it's here runtime polymorphism. In this simple case the compiler might optimize it out (_provided_ it can inline `sayHelloNTimes()`, which we think of as being in a library, likely another compilation unit), but if `Base&` - or the corresponding pointer - is passed around / stored in the objects of the library. In that case, such optimization is infeasible. In general, don't think that stack equals non-polymorphism and heap equals polymorphism, there are counterexamples for both.